# L1 error of estimators

Tags: st.statistics, estimation-theory

I came across the following problem and I have no clue how to approach it. I am looking for help with directions or references.

Consider the $\alpha$-stable distribution with unknown true mean $\mu$, and we want to estimate this mean by taking samples $X_1, X_2, \cdots$. The sample mean estimator $\bar{\mu}_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ would have the L-1 error decay with a rate of $n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}$. More specifically,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[|\bar{\mu}_n - \mu|\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\bigg|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \mu\bigg|\right]\sim n^{\frac{1}{\alpha}-1}
\end{equation}

My question is: if there exist other estimators that could have the L-1 error decaying with a faster rate than the sample mean estimator.

Since $\alpha$-stable distribution is heavy-tailed, I have tried other estimators specifically designed for heavy-tailed distribution，and the decaying rate could not beat the sample mean estimator. So right now I kind of believe no estimator could win sample mean estimator w.r.t this L-1 asymptotic decaying rate (when I say 'win' I mean the n's power is smaller than $1-1/\alpha$)

My thinking is: I want to connect this problem to the famous Cramer Rao's lower bound for the variance of an unbiased estimator. But the gap here is: the Fishers-information-related bound is the L-2 error instead of the L-1 error. So I am wondering if there are some theorems providing a lower bound for estimators in terms of the L1 error.